# ssh-keyscan: How confirm that the public keys asked and received are really authentic?

Tags: ssh, security, openssh, ssh-keygen

In the **server** exists in the `/etc/ssh/` directory files such as:

```
ssh_hosts_rsa_key.pub
ssh_hosts_ecdsa_key.pub
ssh_hosts_ed25519_key.pub
```

They contain the public keys according with a key type, such as `rsa`, `ecdsa` etc

If in the **client** are executed the following commands:

```
# Retrieve and Show all the public keys content
ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X

# Retrieve all the public keys content and Show the fingerprint of them 
ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X | ssh-keygen -lf -
```

The outputs are the `public keys` and `fingerprint` respectively

#### Observation

- The data shown through the `ssh-keyscan` command comes from the files available in the `/etc/ssh` directory located in the server

#### Concern

- I read in the web that the server could be replaced by one fake OR the communication between the client/server can be intercepted and therefore compromised

So therefore even is if executed the following command:

```
ssh-keyscan [-H] 192.168.1.X >> ~/home/<username>/public_keys
```

Where `public_keys` is a custom file just to keep the data received from the server and do later a verification/analysis. So ...

**Question**

- How confirm that the *public keys* asked and received through the `ssh-keygen` command are really authentic?

The purpose is avoid execute

```
ssh-keyscan [-H] 192.168.1.X >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

and add tainted data in the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, and finally send crucial data to a fake destination, starting with the *public key* of the client itself.

I thought the admin in the server would share to the client these `.pub` files, it through

- by email
- by a ftp access

and thus the client can:

- use the mentioned `public_keys` file to do a simple comparison with content of the `.pub` files. Should be equal
- use the `ssh-keygen` command with the `-lvf` options to generate the `fingerprint` directly of the `.pub` files and do a quick comparison against `ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X | ssh-keygen -lf -` command. Should be equal too

It would be the most obvious approach at a first glance, it perhaps for a "small" LAN/WAN would have sense, but assuming the admin don't want share these files due of any policy ... how to answer my question? - Of course the other worst scenario is if the admin's email/ftp was compromised too.

Comment: This is the SSH TOFU problem.  There are a number of ways admins try to solve this, but no standard method.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use

Comment: "the admin don't want share these files due of any policy", how can such a question be answered by anybody other than the admin? Who knows what arbitrary nonsensical restrictions such an admin might have?

Comment: That's why I put that sentence